# どか in 「勝手にどか行っちゃう駄目だよ」

Tags: grammar, translation

I encountered this sentence in the Kanon anime ep 1 13:05 (according to my JP subs):

じゃ　そこにいってね。勝手にどか行っちゃう駄目だよ。

This is Nayuki telling Yuuichi not to go anywhere while he waits outside the store for her.

I know that いっちゃう is いってしまう (don't accidentally/unexpectedly wander off) and that 勝手に is arbitrarily/based on his whims. And だめだよ is "must not". But it's not clear to me what the どか　is doing there. Dictionaries not turning anything up. Is it a transcription error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a transcription error.

It says

> じゃ　そこにいてね。勝手にどっか行っちゃ、だめだよ。

- そこにいてね = stay there
- どっか = somewhere, elsewhere

For 行っちゃ = 行っては, your understanding is correct.

Overall, it means "Then, stay there. Don't go elsewhere on your whims (～without telling me)."

Comment: Thank you, in the audio it does sound like she's saying どっか. This is the not the first time I got confused by a missing っ. I think in the future I'll try inserting っ to try to detect this kind of transcription error myself.